# Pandas: generate date range in a specific format

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, time-series

I would like to generate date range in the string format. For example `20160101`, `20160102`...

I have done the following:

```
import pandas as pd

dateRange = pd.date_range('20160101', periods = 100)
```

The first element is `dateRange[0] = Timestamp('2016-01-01 00:00:00', offset='D')`

How do I get the desired output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert it back to string:

```
dateRange = pd.date_range('20160101', periods = 5)
dateRange.strftime('%Y%m%d')
Out: 
array(['20160101', '20160102', '20160103', '20160104', '20160105'], 
      dtype='<U8')
```